# jQuery: Prevent multiple clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to prevent mutiple clicks on a link and I need to wait until the function's complete before allowing another click on the same link.

However, everything I do, the multiple clicks is always allowed.

This is my code:

```
var active = false;

$('#rotRight').live('click', function(){
        if (active) {
        return;
    }

    $(this).attr('id', 'rotRight1');
    var curAngle = parseInt($(".selected").getRotateAngle()) || 0;


    if($(".selected").rotate({
        angle: curAngle,
        animateTo: curAngle - 90

    })){
        active = true;
    }
    $(this).attr('id', 'rotRight');
    active = false;
});
```

I know I'm in the right path. I just need someone to let me know what i'm missing or if I'm doing something wrong please.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: try remove `var` from the statement `var active = false;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rotate plugin has a [callback](http://jqueryrotate.com/) where you can reset the active flag value

```
var active = false;

$('#rotRight').live('click', function() {
  if (active) {
    return;
  }

  var curAngle = parseInt($(".selected").getRotateAngle()) || 0;

  active = true;
  $(".selected").rotate({
    angle: curAngle,
    animateTo: curAngle - 90,
    callback: function() {
      active = false;
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try preventing default behaviour first before returning

```
var active = false;

$('#rotRight').live('click', function(e){
    if (active) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default behaviour before returning
        return;
    }

    ... 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always create an overlay (loading screen), stopping the user doing anything till the process is completed via a full screen div with the following css:

```
#overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    z-index: 999;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}​
```

This will do the following: https://gyazo.com/aa833914eda1c39d3b8198db2b32dc41

Makes all content un-clickable until after the loading screen has finished.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the [Data attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) on your link. Like that, you can set the "active" property on the link itself and act in consequence. Jquery handle that system with $().data(string) method. I think it's cleaner than using a global "active" var.

```
$('#rotRight').live('click', function() {
  if ($(this).data("active") != undefined && $(this).data("active") == true) {
    return;
  }

  var curAngle = parseInt($(".selected").getRotateAngle()) || 0;

  $(this).data("active") = true;
  var self = $(this);
  $(".selected").rotate({
    angle: curAngle,
    animateTo: curAngle - 90,
    callback: function() {
      self.data("active") = false;
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#rotRight').live('click', function(e) {
    if (e.handled!=true) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default behaviour before returning
        return;
    }
    e.handled=true;
});
```